# where to put limit in mysqli query in pagination

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

so my query is here i'm doing pagination using php now whenever i put limit in my query it gives this error Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\Deshboard.php on line 292

```
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *

 FROM 
 notes LIMIT $start,$limit

INNER JOIN 
 subjects

 ON

subjects.subject_id = notes.subject_id
WHERE   by_teacher='".$_SESSION['admin_id']."'," );
```

Comment: Two reasons: there's a comma after your where clause, and LIMIT **must** be at the end of your query.

Comment: The MySQL documentation has syntax diagrams for every type of query. Why would you need to post here when you can just go to the web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow!

I've been reading over the query multiple times now to create a solid answer for you and must start by distressing the importance of [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples)  when accepting parameters. This to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) / malicious attacks on your database.

With that out of the way, according to the [SQL SELECT-syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), `LIMIT` should be after the `WHERE` statement.

The PHP code should end up looking something like this:

```
    // prepare a mysqli query with notes.by_teacher requiring
    // a parameter (indicated by the question mark)
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
        $conn, 'SELECT * FROM notes 
            INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.subject_id = notes.note_id
            WHERE notes.by_teacher=?
            LIMIT ?,?'
    );

    // set the first parameter as type string (s)
    // to the value of $_SESSION['admin_id']
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sii', $_SESSION['admin_id'], $start, $limit);
```

Comment: Why don't you use parameters for $start,$limit?